# Inject npm dependences by gulp

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, dependency-injection, gulp

I use gulp compilator for angular. I used bower dependences and I moved all of them to npm. I have problem with injecting dependences to script. It's my current code to injecting. How change wiredep to another library to handle npm inject because I have Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined and var angular = require(angular) not work. Is it any simple solution to inject npm dependences to script without require ect? How do it by require if not?

```
var injectStyles = gulp.src([
    paths.tmp + '/serve/{app,components,lib}/**/*.css',
    paths.src + '/{app,components,lib}/**/*.css',
    '!' + paths.tmp + '/serve/app/vendor.css'
], {read: false});

var injectScripts = gulp.src([
    paths.src + '/{app,components,lib}/**/*.js',
    paths.tmp + '/serve/build/*.js',
    '!' + paths.src + '/{app,components}/**/*.spec.js',
    '!' + paths.src + '/{app,components}/**/*.mock.js'
]).pipe($.angularFilesort());

var injectOptions = {
    ignorePath: [paths.src, paths.tmp + '/serve', paths.tmp + '/build'],
    addRootSlash: false
};

var wiredepOptions = {
    directory: 'bower_components',
    exclude: [/bootstrap\.css/, /bootstrap\.css/, /foundation\.css/]
};

return gulp.src(paths.src + '/*.html')
    .pipe($.inject(injectStyles, injectOptions))
    .pipe($.inject(injectScripts, injectOptions))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.tmp + '/serve'));
```

Comment: I recommed https://bower.io/blog/2017/how-to-migrate-away-from-bower/ this document for 'leaving bower'